# slope of a plane

Tags: 3d

I'm trying to understand the math behind 3d perspective clipping algorithm

*dixit:*

We need four constant to express the equations of the four side planes. These are the slopes of the planes in relation to the z-axis. Figure 6.27 shows a vertical cross section through the frustrum and will help in determing the slopes for the top and bottom planes. A similar situation exists for the left and right planes:

slope of the right plane: $S_R=1/2*(wxh-wxl)/(d+wzl)$

slope of the left plane: $S_L=-1/2*(wxh-wxl)/(d+wzl)$

slope of the top plane: $S_T=1/2*(wyh-wyl)/(d+wzl)$

slope of the bottom plane: $S_B=-1/2*(wyh-wyl)/(d+wzl)$

With these constants the equations of the planes are:

$$
L: x = wxl + S_L(z-wzl) \\
R: x = wxh + S_R(z-wzl) \\
B: y = wyl + S_B(z-wzl) \\
T: y = wyh + S_T(z-wzl) \\
N: z = wzl \\
F: z = wzh
$$

[image: Figure 627 Cross section through the view volume]

I don't understand how the slope of each planes has been calculated, also the respectives equations of the planes looks like the equation of the line

Comment: continues here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888768/intersection-between-2-lines