# Intersection between 2 lines

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is related to 3d perspective clipping, in other words, clipping a polygon against a truncated pyramided (frustrum), the author uses similar triangles to define the slope of each plane that build the frustum, for example, for the top plane, has a slope $$\frac 12\frac{\text{wyh}-\text{wyl}}{d+\text{wzl}},$$

where $\frac{\text{wyh}-\text{wyl}}2$ is the length from bottom to top of the triangle and $d+\text{wzl}$ is the length from left to right of the triangle.

[image]

with this slope, his construct a line in intercept form, so the equation of the plane for the top boundary is: $$y=\text{wyh}+\left(\frac 12\frac{\text{wyh}-\text{wyl}}{d+\text{wzl}}\right)(z-\text{wzl})$$

The thing that I don't understand is how he is calculating the intersection point

*dixit:*

the intersection of a line from $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ with these six planes are found as follows. For the six planes we compute six $t$-values *(I'm only showing the top boundary case for simplicity)*

$$
S_T=\text{SlopeTop}=\frac 12\frac{\text{wyh}-\text{wyl}}{d+\text{wzl}} \\
t_T= \frac{y_1-\text{wyh}+S_T(\text{wzl}-z_1)}{y_1-y_2 + S_T(z_2-z_1)}
$$

So, I don't know what reasosing he is using to get $t_T$ equation

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: I have do nothing, because I only know how to calculate the intersection when I know a value from the intersection point, but in this situation I only know that these 2 lines intersect, just that

Comment: already solve here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889466/intersection-of-two-lines-computing-the-t-value/889474#889474

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to find the intersection between the line $y=mx + b$ and the line between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$

Two steps will solve your problem:

1. Find the formula for the line between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.
2. Having two formulas for two lines, calculate their intersection.

Try to do each of the steps. Edit your question with results. Then, if something goes wrong, we can help you further.

Comment: I'm just made a major edit to my question