# Intersection of two lines, computing the t-value

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ that define my line, and also I have the other line in intercept slope form, $y=mx+b$, I know that these two lines intersect, so, I was wondering how to compute t-value that gives me the intersection point by using it in the parameterized line representation of the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Your first line has points of the form $((1-t)x_1 + tx_2, (1-t)y_1 + ty_2)$, so substitute this into the equation for the second line $y=mx+ b$ to get $$ (1-t)y_1 + ty_2 = m((1-t)x_1 + tx_2)+b$$ which is a linear equation which you can solve for $t$ and then use that value of $t$ in the first expression to find the point of intersection.

Comment: fantastic, it works!! it took me a while to find out the t-value :P, thanks so much Henry!